# how to track movements of a person in windows phone using GeoCoordinateWatcher?

Tags: windows-phone-7

From a particular start point, I want to track a person's movement in terms of longitude, latitude and altitude  using GeoCoordinateWatcher in windows phone 7

And when that person reaches to the same start point (after making circles or rectangles )I want to stop tracking.

Any idea how to implement this ?

Comment: so whats is the problem?

Comment: I know we have to use GeoCoordinateWatcher for this.             User need not to make an exact circle or rectangle.It can be any other shape but when user comes back to the same position (need not to be 100% accurate which means not the same point but alteast very close to the same start point .e.g. one foot distance) then i should stop my counter.
 

So the difference between longitude or  latitude or altitude should be calculated to find if the person has moved back to the same start point.I am not sure which one i should consider .Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

GeoCoordinateWatcher API helps intracking the position.